# Можно на форуме создать информационно-новостной блок?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Можно на форуме организовать **информационно-новостной блок** на тему **русского языка**: новые работы российских лингвистов, изменения в словарях, новые методики обучения, изменения в экзаменационных правилах и т.д. Почему только вопросы-ответы — и больше ничего?

Например:

Рособрнадзор раскрыл изменения в заданиях основного государственного экзамена (ОГЭ), который сдают выпускники девятых классов. **В 2020 году введены новые задания, проверяющие умения осуществлять информационный поиск, анализировать информацию.** Во время ОГЭ выпускники покажут умение **формулировать и аргументировать свое мнение.**

При этом часть заданий, «хорошо знакомых школам», останется, но по некоторым дисциплинам их число изменится. Так, **в работе по русскому языку в 2020 году количество заданий сократится с 15 до 9.**..

До 2024 года в России планируется реализовать **нацпроект «Образование».** В него, в частности, входит федеральный проект **«Современная школа»,** в рамках которого в российских школах будут внедряться **новые методы и программы обучения,** тогда как многие **привычные форматы окончательно уйдут в прошлое.**

Мне лично интересно, **с какими форматами** нам предстоит расстаться.